# How to translate Number(1,0) data type in oracle sql to hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a table that has a column as data type number(1,0) and title as answer. This column could hold either value of 1 or 0. I have a java entity model that represents this table using hibernate (v4.1.11). I am having a difficulty in mapping number(1,0) from oracle sql to hibernate. Do I even need an annotation for it? Having int type would be suffice?

```
@Entity
@Table(name="FOO")
public class Foo {

    @Column(name="ANSWER")
    @<what annotation?>
    private int answer;
```

Comment: I just came across to a page (https://vladmihalcea.com/2014/06/10/a-beginners-guide-to-hibernate-types/) in where it maps hibernate type to jdbc and java type. Using NumericBooleanType as annotation and change int to boolean would be right way to do it?

Comment: If you can change or design your data model, I would also ask you consider yes_no type which may be more suitable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Column is sufficient. Generally Type annotations are not needed unless you specifically want to override. Considering your case, it would be ideal to declare it as Boolean and use `@Type NumericBooleanType` or even `YesNoType`. If you want to override using custom type, please refer @TypeDef section in hibernate documentation https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html_single/.